# Bot Framework Maintaining User State

Tags: c#, state, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Previously i was using Microsoft state service to maintain user state in my bot. Now that Microsoft has stopped supporting state service, i have written a static object to store user data as shown below. Just wanted to know is this a right approach to maintain user state because at once around 8000 user might be using the application. I am just worried if it will cause some concurrent. Please suggest if there is a better way to maintain user state in bot framework

```
    private static object objectLock = new object();
    public void SetBotCache(T CaceData, string userID)
    {

  _sessionData.AddOrUpdate(userID, CaceData, (key, oldValue) => CaceData);

    }

    public T GetBotCache(string userID)
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            if (_sessionData.Count > 0)
            {
                return _sessionData.First(a => a.Key == userID).Value;
            }
            else
            {
               return default(T);
            }
        }
    }

    public void RemoveCache(string userID)
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            T res;
            _sessionData.TryRemove(userID, out res);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Bot Framework engineers have provided **BotBuilder-Azure** specifically for this purpose: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/

The Bot Framework blog also provides instructions for how to setup **Azure Table Storage** and **DocumentDb** (now **CosmosDb**): 
https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/18/saving-state-azure-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

> i have written a static object to store user data as shown below. Just wanted to know is this a right approach to maintain user state because at once around 8000 user might be using the application.

It seems that you implement in-memory cache for storing bot user data by yourself, the approach is ok for testing purposes. As we know, the data stored with in-memory is non-persistent, if the bot application restart or crash, the data been cached will be lost, so it is not recommended for production environments.

You said your bot application will published on production server for about 8000 users using. As Eric Dahlvang mentioned, in production environments, you can use Azure Extensions to store your [bot's state data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state) in either Table Storage, CosmosDB, or SQL.